# How to rename .env variables in package.json?

Tags: shell, npm, environment-variables, package.json, npm-scripts

### What I have

I have multiple projects using Percy for Cypress where I set the `PERCY_TOKEN` env variable inside the `.env` file. The token is different for each project. In the CI I set different env variables for each project, but locally I have to do it in the `.env` file. Because of this, I have to edit the `.env` file whenever I change between projects.

### Goal

I would like to set them in the `.env` file this way:

```
PROJECT_A_PERCY_TOKEN=tokenhash1
PROJECT_B_PERCY_TOKEN=tokenhash2
```

So later I could rename these variables to `PERCY_TOKEN`, eliminating the need to constantly change the `.env` file.

### What I tried

I'm trying to do this inside the `package.json` file's `scripts` property. Unfortunately `echo $PROJECT_A_PERCY_TOKEN` prints nothing. I know that I could create a shell/python/js script that parses the `.env` file, then passes the value back or calls `npm run` directly but I would like to do this without an external script.

### Problem

It appears to me that I can't access the env variables inside `package.json`. Is there a way to rename the variable only using the npm script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr

If the package you try to configure has the ability to do configuration via a JavaScript file, you can add the renaming at the beginning of it:

```
process.env.PERCY_TOKEN = process.env.CYPRESS_PERCY_SALESFORCE_TOKEN;
```

### Explanation

While this isn't the solution I was looking for, it is a workaround for this specific use case. [Percy supports JavaScript config files](https://docs.percy.io/docs/cli-configuration#files) so I migrated my YAML config file, then I logged `process.env` and the `.env` file's variables were there, so I just need to copy the correct one. This might work for other packages that support JavaScript config files (or some alternative kind of hook/preloader where custom code can be placed), but if they don't, then the question is still unanswered.